# ¿Cómo se eliminan las tildes de una palabra que introduce el usuario?

Tags: java, string

Esta vez mi problema de Java consiste en un programa donde el usuario introduzca una frase, el código invierta esa frase y después compare si se puede leer al revés, las condiciones para el código son:

1. Ignorar las tildes de las letras (no tengo idea de eso).
2. Ignorar las mayúsculas e minúsculas de la frase (trabajando en eso).
3. Ignorar si en la frase hay espacios (hecho).
4. Invertir la frase y compararla si se puede leer igual al revés (hecho).

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args){
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Introduce una frase");
       String frase = sc.nextLine();
       String FI = " ";


       for(int i = frase.length()-1; i >= 0; i--){
           FI += frase.charAt(i);
       }



       String frase2 = (frase.replace(" ",""));
       frase2.toLowerCase();
       String FI2 = (FI.replace(" ",""));
       FI2.toLowerCase();


       if(frase2.equals(FI2)){
           System.out.println("Tu frase se lee igual al revez: " + frase2 + " == " + FI2);
       }else{
           System.out.println("Tu frase no se lee igual al revez: " + frase2 + " != " + FI2);
       }
   }
   ```

Se agradecería mucho si me dijeran lo de las tildes.

Comment: ¿se vale usar librerias de terceros o lo de las tildes debe ser un método que escribas a mano?

Comment: Si, por mi esta bien

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dado que se menciona que se puede usar librerías de terceros mi recomendación es usar la clase  `StringUtils`  que forma parte de `commons-lang3`.

`StringUtils` cuenta con el método estático `stripAccents` que se encarga de eliminar las tildes de las letras que vienen en las palabras de una cadena.

Por ejemplo dada la cadena:

```
"Él, Álva, SÍ, LOCIÓN, ÚNION, á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, Ü"
```

La invocación:

```
StringUtils.stripAccents("Él, Álva, SÍ, LOCIÓN, ÚNION, á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, Ü");
```

Devolverá la cadena:

```
"El, Alva, SI, LOCION, UNION, a, e, i, o, u, u, U"
```

La liga a la librería es la siguiente:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/